# Apache poi workbookfactory create HSSFWorkbook from xlsx, But I expect XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I'm trying to create XSSFWorkbook from file.xlsx by calling:

```
1. XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(file) -> return HSSFWorkbook
2. WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(file) -> While trying to invoke 'createWorkbook' on factory org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory and arguments [path to file.xlsx]
3. OPCPackage.open(file) -> The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
4. XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file)) -> The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)
```

I need to read a file as **XSSFWorkbook** to read and set new params to chart.
Any ideas, why I catch this errors and why way from item 1 returns **HSSFWorkbook**?

I checked several times, the file has .xlsx extension.

Comment: All you get tells you that your `file` contains data in a `OLE2` `BIFF` format which is the binary format of a `Excel 97 - 2003` workbook. Even when the file is named `*.xlsx` that does not change the content though. The fie content is the content of a `Excel 97 - 2003` workbook.

Comment: @AxelRichter Okay, thanks!
I think the reason is that file contains macro.
I tried to find ways to open file without macro, but failed with it. Do you know how i can open this file as XSSFWorkbook?

Comment: "I think the reason is that file contains macro": Definitely not. What happens if you are opening that file using `Excel`?

Comment: it opened without errors. I use WPS office

Comment: there's a simple check without using Excel and WPS which works for not encrypted files. If you rename the file to *.zip and you can open it, it's 98% a .xlsx (exceptions are e.g. embedded calculation sheets used for charts) ... if you can't unzip, it's an old Biff *.xls or a faked xls like html or csv file